# Write an uploads metadata with information stored data in Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been hitting my head against the wall on this for about 2 hours and I think I've just lost sight of the problem a bit.

I have an incremental field saved as "index" that upon a file upload starting has it's value increase by 1.

I am able to query the database and pull the value for index to the console and receive the updated value.

I can't for the life of me work out how to insert the value I've created and subsequently logged to the console (definitely doesn't need to be logged just did this to prove to myself I wasn't going insane) into the uploads metadata at the next stage of the script. I have tried everything I can think of - I've watched about an hour of youtube videos, and I can safely say beyond a shadow of a doubt I could turn my app into a running counter of peoples file uploads but I can't add it to their upload metadata!

Help me stack overflow you're my only hope!

Code below hopefully outlines the issue - the query is going into the variable indexRef but the actual info I need is in the nested variable "key" which is just the data snapshot value. This seems like it should be so easy.

```
        var indexRef = firebase.database().ref('index');
        indexRef.once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot){
          var key = snapshot.val()
          console.log(key)
        })
        var imagekey = firebase.database().ref('images/').push().key;
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        var updates = {};
        var postData = {
            url: downloadURL,
            score: 1500,
            index: indexRef,
            user: user.uid
        };            
        updates ['/images/'+imagekey] = postData;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Thanks in advance and I apologise if the answer to this is trivial and I've wasted someones time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the `then` method returns promises https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html

```
    var indexRef = firebase.database().ref('index');

    // Declare variables outside of block to access within
    var imagekey = firebase.database().ref('images/').push().key;
    var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    var updates = {};

    indexRef.once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot){
      var key = snapshot.val()
      // Return key variable for use
      return key;
    })
   .then(function(key){
     // You can now access the key variable in here
    var postData = {
        url: downloadURL,
        score: 1500,
        index: key,
        user: user.uid
    };            
    updates ['/images/'+imagekey] = postData;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates); 
   })
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I could kiss you. I’ve stared at that for hours like an idiot! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped you :)